# How to download builds from the Jfrog and deploy into platforms

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, jfrog-cli

I'm very new to Jfrog and we are downloading the builds (.apk) from Jfrog and installing the build into the android mobile by manually. I just want to automate this process. I started to looking the ways to achieve this and figured out that through REST API and other one is Jfrog cli.

I don't see the API token to get it from my corporate jfrog account, but i can able to download the build for some of the repository. Also I heard about sync artifact concept, But I'm not sure how can I achieve this and I need some input to kick start things.